# Oracle Identity column with custom grouping column

Tags: java, oracle, max, identity-column, oracle19c

I am working on a requirement where I need to populate a ****unique** **constant** identifier on a row which is the manager row and unique in each department**. My table structure is

```
CREATE
  TABLE TEST_ORGANIZATION
  (
    EMPLOYEE_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    MANAGER_ID    NUMBER,
    FIRST_NAME    VARCHAR2(256),
    DEPARTMENT_ID VARCHAR2(28) NOT NULL,
    UUID          VARCHAR2(28) ,
    PRIMARY KEY(UUID)
  );
```

This table contains information as.

| UUID | DEPARTMENT_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_ID | FIRST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| radmon1 | finance | employee1 |  | John B |
| radmon2 | finance | employee2 | employee1 | Michal |
| radmon3 | finance | employee3 | employee1 | Ronaldo |
| radmon4 | finance | employee4 | employee1 | Thomas |
| radmon5 | finance | employee5 |  | Percey |
| radmon6 | account | employee6 |  | Stacy |
| radmon7 | account | employee7 |  | Jordan |
| radmon8 | account | employee8 | employee6 | Micky |
| radmon9 | account | employee9 | employee6 | Author |
| radmon10 | account | employee10 | employee6 | Gordan |

I would like to add another column to the table to provide a sequence to managers only (`where Manager_ID is null`). But, the sequence should be grouped with `DEPARTMENT_ID`

`ALTER TABLE TEST_ORGANIZATION ADD SEQUENCE_ID NUMBER`

| UUID | DEPARTMENT_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_ID | FIRST_NAME | SEQUENCE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| radmon1 | finance | employee1 |  | John B | 1 |
| radmon2 | finance | employee2 | employee1 | Michal |  |
| radmon3 | finance | employee3 | employee1 | Ronaldo |  |
| radmon4 | finance | employee4 | employee1 | Thomas |  |
| radmon5 | finance | employee5 |  | Percey | 2 |
| radmon6 | account | employee6 |  | Stacy | 1 |
| radmon7 | account | employee7 |  | Jordan | 2 |
| radmon8 | account | employee8 | employee6 | Micky |  |
| radmon9 | account | employee9 | employee6 | Author |  |
| radmon10 | account | employee10 | employee6 | Gordan |  |

I tried using sequence and identity columns added after oracle 12/19c.

I could it programmatically from backend service and update `SEQUENCE_ID` using
`Select NVL(MAX(SEQUENCE_ID), 0) + 1 FROM TEST_ORGANIZATION WHERE MANAGER_ID is NULL AND DEPARTMENT_ID = ?`  query. But, I would like to know if there is any function in Oracle 19c to handle this behaviour on the Database side itself.

Comment: What's the purpose of this sequence_id column? Is it to be part of a constraint, or for display purposes? You could always add a virtual column to the table that generates the value on-the-fly via an analytic function, but this wouldn't be a permanent value and it'd be calculated every time that column was queried.

Comment: It is to have a unique identifier on a row which is the manager row and unique in each department.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT d1.*,
       1 AS f,
       CASE WHEN manager_id is null then
          RANK() OVER (partition by department_ID order by manager_id nulls first,employee_id)
       end as sequenc
FROM   (
         SELECT 'radmon1' AS UUID,'finance' AS DEPARTMENT_ID,'employee1' AS EMPLOYEE_ID,'' AS MANAGER_ID,'John B' AS    FIRST_NAME          from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon2','finance','employee2','employee1','Michal'     from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon3','finance','employee3','employee1','Ronaldo'    from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon4','finance','employee4','employee1','Thomas'     from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon5','finance','employee5','','Percey'         from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon6','account','employee6','','Stacy'              from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon7','account','employee7','','Jordan'            from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon8','account','employee8','employee6','Micky'      from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon9','account','employee9','employee6','Author'     from dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 'radmon10','account','employee10','employee6','Gordan'   from dual
       )d1;
```